# Issue with using fscanf() in a loop

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

Hopefully this isn't a question someone has asked before, I've looked through previously asked questions but none of them seemed to quite apply to my problem.

I'm having some issues with a program I'm working on to read lines of text from a file. The format of the file I'm trying to read is:

```
10
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
first_name     last_name     long_int_number
```

(You'll notice 10 also represents the number of items in the list.)

The code I have written is:

```
struct student
{
  long studentNumber;
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
};

struct student *readFile(char *fileName, int *numOfStudents)
{
    struct student readStudents[10];
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    char *buff;

fp=fopen(fileName,"r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",numOfStudents);
for (i=0;i<*numOfStudents;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp,"%s",readStudents[i].firstName);
    //printf("%s\n",readStudents[i].firstName);
    fscanf(fp,"%s ",readStudents[i].lastName);
    //printf("%s\n",readStudents[i].lastName);
    fscanf(fp,"%ld",&readStudents[i].studentNumber);
    //printf("%ld\n",readStudents[i].studentNumber);
}
fclose(fp);

/*the remaining code*/

}
```

I have commented out the printf statements that I was using to see where my error had occurred. Basically, it correctly reads numOfStudents and then correctly executes the first loop, however after this the program crashes. I am not certain why this is occuring. Originally I thought it was because it was having an issue reading the new line, but that probably isn't the issue because there is a new line between 10 and the first set of student info. I am fairly new to programming, and any help that you could provide would be very helpful!

Thank you. :)

Comment: looks like you're not allocating space for `firstname`, or `lastname` before writing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've looked through previously asked questions but none of them seemed to quite apply to my problem.

This is an exact duplicate of literally dozens of identical questions. You haven't allocate memory for the pointers `readStudents[i].firstName`, so they are uninitialized, and accessing the memory pointed to by them results in undefined behavior, which manifests as a crash. You will need to either use arrays as your structure members, or `malloc()`ate memory dynamically.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the repeated question, I guess I was just confused as to why my program would always run correctly for the first run through loop and cease to work after this. As I said, I'm fairly a new programmer so these things kind of fly right over my head sometimes.